# Tablesorter does only filter on first word of entry

Tags: javascript, tablesorter

I have an older php app that uses Matt Kruse's table javascript sorter.  I have been working with a change I need for a couple of days now and I think I need to stop and find out if this is even possible.

Using his [table.js](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/table/) in an app, works just fine, but one client just brought to my attention that the filter only searches on the first word, not all the text, so for example, if on of the columns has Air Plane, Def Jamm, Razor Edge and Jamm Drive - when you search/filter in the top sort/filter box on "Air" the Air Plane line will filter out, but if you search on "Plane" nothing is returned.

Has anyone encountered this?  If so, is it possible to fix/adjust? If so, how to do a search on Jamm and have everyrow that has Jamm in it returned.

Comment: The [examples page](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/table/examples.php) seems to suggest that you can implement your own custom filter, if the out-of-the-box ones are not to your liking.

Comment: It is not quite show how to filter on any letter in the filter field, so I suspect that this must not be an option.

Comment: Correct.  That's canned functionality, added to your table by using a CSS class, probably the `table-filterable` class.  To change the behavior, you have to implement a custom filter, or tweak the author's source code for `table-filterable`.